# What is “Secure Boot chain-loading bootloader (Microsoft-signed binary)" and why is Ubuntu 20.04 trying to install it on my system?

Tags: uefi, bootloader

It seems to be part of the [shim-signed package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/shim-signed).  (Credit: @neikas)  That package description says: "Its purpose is to allow a small, infrequently-changing binary to be signed by the UEFI CA, while allowing an OS distributor to revision their main bootloader independently of the CA."   But why am I getting this, given that I am running Ubuntu -- not Microsoft?

[image: Screenshot]

See also related question: [How to remove “Secure Boot chain-loading bootloader (Microsoft-signed binary) ”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360572/how-to-remove-secure-boot-chain-loading-bootloader-microsoft-signed-binary)

Comment: It's *signed* by Microsoft https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot